# Why does `ns(0.8)` or `ns(c(0.8))` return `NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`?

Tags: r, spline, cubic-spline

Why does `ns(0.8)` or `ns(c(0.8))` return `NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`?

`ns(c(0.8, 1.0))` works fine but I wonder why giving just 1 value to `ns` causes a `NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`.

Example:

```
> library(splines)
> ns(0.8)
Error in qr.default(t(const)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)


> ns(c(0.8, 1.0))
             1
[1,] 0.0000000
[2,] 0.8017837
attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
numeric(0)
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1] 0.8 1.0
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

Comment: Can you explain how you think fitting a spline to one point _should_ work? `ns()` depends on the first argument insofar as it can be used to determine knot placement (including boundary knots). With only one data point, there is not enough information to make a sensible selection and it makes sense for the method to fail.

Comment: @stephematician sounds like a better error message

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: After a user comment, I realized my answer was irrelevant. However I'm not deleting it for now since I emailed the R-Core team about the (very real) discrepancy in the documentation and referred to this post in the email.

---

There is a discrepancy in the `ns()` function's documentation for the 2nd argument, `df`:

> degrees of freedom. One can supply df rather than knots; ns() then
>   chooses df - 1 - intercept knots at suitably chosen quantiles of x
>   (which will ignore missing values). The default, df = 1, corresponds
>   to no knots.

The actual default value is not 1, but `NULL`, as we can see in the *Usage* section:

> ns(x, df = NULL, knots = NULL, intercept = FALSE,    Boundary.knots =
>   range(x))

Comment: Btw I just emailed the R-Core dev team about this.

Comment: @user20650 Just added it to my answer.

Comment: Oh, right... Hmm well that makes my answer rather irrelevant! :D

Comment: Thank you, @Dominic Comtois, but you should rather use a public mailing list (R-help or ..), see https://www.r-project.org/mail.html  or report it differently if you are confident about bug, see https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html

Answer (score 3):

I agree the error message is not user friendly.. so a change seems rational at least for that.   We have to look and see if ns(<1 number>), say `ns(pi)` can make sense at all... I'd rather discuss that on the R-devel mailing list (https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) instead of here.

I also agree with @Dominic Comtois  that the help page should be amended, as the default has not been `1` for a long time.

Last but not least, note that `ns()`  and `bs()` should be considered as a pair as they were designed that way.   As their main use had been in model formulas to generate a `model.matrix()`,  I tend to agree that it *would* be nice if we can come up with a rational  non-error result for the `ns(pi)` case.  Thank you both for raising the issue!!

Comment: As it happen this got me intrigued... and  ... tada! ..  I've improved R's `ns()` so that indeed it "now" (*) works to use  `ns(pi)` notably it now will work to use   `lm(y ~ x1 + ns(x2) + ...,  data = myD)`  even in the ("not so frequent" ;-) case where `myD` has only one observation.
--
*) in R-devel for now, but I will port it to 'R 3.4.1 patched' too, so it will be in the next version of R.